# html2canvas - is there to print a hidden DIV to pdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf, html2canvas

**Background**

I have a table of records that uses the "tabulator" control to allow users to sort, filter etc.
once they have the results they want in the table, I need to provide a way for users trigger the creation of a PDF per row, using a PDF template.
At the top of the page, I have a drop down menu where they can select a template.  For example, it will have options like this:

- pdf with blue logo
- pdf with pink logo

etc.

**What I know how to do:**
1.  I know how to loop through the selected records in my table in jquery
2.  I know how to create a basic jsPDF document.
3.  The "template" mechanism will simply be 2 different  that are predefined in the webpage.  Depending on which option they select in the dropdown, I can determine which logo to include.

**Problem**

It seems that unless the DIVs that will be included in the PDF are visible, html2canvas won't work.

So far, this is the prototype code I've been playing with: 
(other than the fact that the DIV i'm trying to PDF shows on the screen, everything else works.)

```
<div id="bluetemplate" class="ug_logo_style" style="display: none">
    <img class="bluelogo"></img>
</div>
<div id="pinktemplate" class="ug_logo_style" style="display: none">
    <img class="pinklogo"></img>
</div>

$("#templatedropdown").change(function(){
   var selectedtemplate = this.value;
   switch (selectedtemplate){
        case 'blue':
            $("div#bluetemplate").show();
            $("div#pinktemplate").hide();
            break;
        case 'pink':
            $("div#pinktemplate").show();
            $("div#bluetemplate").hide();
            break;
   }
});

$("#btntemplate").click(function(){
    switch($('#template option:selected').val()){
        case 'blue':            
            var imgData;
            html2canvas($("#bluetemplate"), {
                useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                       'image/png');
                    var doc = new jsPDF({
                        orientation: 'landscape', 
                        unit:'pt', 
                        format:[400,200]});
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);

                    doc.text(registrant.first_name + " " + registrant.last_name, 10, 100);
                    doc.text(registrant.email, 10, 120);                   
                    doc.save(registrant.event_id + '_' + registrant.id + '.pdf');
                    window.open(imgData);
                }
            });

            break;
        case 'pink':
            var imgData;
            html2canvas($("#pinktemplate"), {
                useCORS: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    imgData = canvas.toDataURL(
                       'image/png');
                    var doc = new jsPDF({
                        orientation: 'landscape', 
                        unit:'pt', 
                        format:[400,200]});
                    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);

                    doc.text(registrant.first_name + " " + registrant.last_name, 10, 100);
                    doc.text(registrant.email, 10, 120);                   
                    doc.save(registrant.event_id + '_' + registrant.id + '.pdf');
                    window.open(imgData);
                }
            });

            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this to your css

```
.html2canvas-container { width: 3000px !important; height: 3000px !important; }
```

Please refer [here](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/117) for issues relating to printing invisible content.